# Codechef December lunchtime 2019 stupid machine

Tags: c++

What is wrong with my code so that it got wrong for second test case.
question link https://www.codechef.com/LTIME79B/problems/STUPMACH/

some part of question is as follows:

There are N boxes in a line (numbered 1 through N). Initially, the boxes are empty, and I need to use the machine to put tokens in them. For each valid i, the i-th box has a maximum capacity Si tokens. I can perform the following operation any number of times: choose an integer L (1≤L≤N) and put one token in each of the boxes 1,2,…,L.

find maximum number of token.

Logic is to add number which is minimum uptill index;

2 5 4 1 3

then 2+2+2+1+1=8 will be the answer.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
 #define forn(i, n) for (int i = 0; i < int(n); i++)

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    forn(j,t)
    {
       long long  n,mn=LONG_MAX;
       cin>>n;
       long long k;

        long long ans=0;
        forn(i,n)
        {
            cin>>k;
            mn=min(mn,k);
            ans=(ans+mn)%1000000007;
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
}
```

editorial is as followws:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/trie_policy.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
typedef tree<int, null_type, less<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> pbds;
typedef trie<string, null_type, trie_string_access_traits<>, pat_trie_tag, trie_prefix_search_node_update> pref_trie;
typedef unsigned long long BITMASK; typedef long long ll; typedef long double ld;
#define has_bit(bit_mask, x) ((bit_mask) & (1Uint << (x)))
#define turn_on_bit(bit_mask, x) (bit_mask |= (1Uint << (x)))
#define turn_off_bit(bit_mask, x) (bit_mask &= (~(1Uint << (x))))
#define smallest_on_bit(bit_mask) (__builtin_ctzint((bit_mask) & (-(bit_mask))))
#define CLOCK_START clock_t chrono_clk_beg = clock()
#define CLOCK_END clock_t chrono_clk_end = clock(); cerr << (double(chrono_clk_end - chrono_clk_beg) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " sec"
#define bug(args ...) cerr << __LINE__ << ">> ", err(new istringstream(string(#args)), args), cerr << '\n'
void err(istringstream *iss) {} template<typename T, typename ... Args> void err(istringstream *iss, const T &_val, const Args & ... args) { string _name; *iss >> _name; if (_name.back()==',') _name.pop_back(); cerr << _name << " = " << _val << "; ", err(iss, args ...); }
#define MOD 1000000007

signed main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        ll n, x;
        cin >> n;
        ll ans = 0, curMin = LONG_MAX;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cin >> x;
            curMin = min(curMin, x);
            ans += curMin;
        }
        cout << ans << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the line `ans=(ans+mn)%1000000007;`. It should be `ans=ans+mn;` because it's not asked in the question to `MOD` the final answer by `10^9+7`. The sum `ans` can exceed `10^9+7` because it's given in question constraints that `1≤Si≤10^9` for each valid i.